# Contact Form 7 : No p element in scope but a p end tag seen

Tags: wordpress, validation, contact-form-7, w3c-validation

I am using contact form 7 plugin on my website. Plugin shortcode generated spaces, new lines, and p tags, which w3 validator say there is not a right.

how  I can change the template or fix it with other ways

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the simple way is that add `add_filter('wpcf7_autop_or_not', '__return_false');` in your **functions.php**

another way is to modify/edit your form and remove all your `\n` (new line characters).

Answer (score 0):

you can also add this to your wp-config.php

```
define( 'WPCF7_AUTOP', false );
```